# How can i pass array of composite type from nodejs to postgresql function?

Tags: arrays, node.js, postgresql

I have a postgres function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_new_views(VARIADIC all_view event_view[])
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    view event_view;
BEGIN
    FOREACH view IN ARRAY all_view LOOP 
        INSERT INTO t_event_views VALUES (view.event_id, view.device_code);
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
```

event_view - this is my composite type :

```
CREATE TYPE event_view (event_id uuid, device_code text);
```

I can use my function through pgAdmin like this:

```
SELECT add_new_views(VARIADIC ARRAY [
    ('b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284', 'asd')::event_view,
    ('b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284', 'asd')::event_view
]);
```

But i need to call it from nodejs. To connect with postgresql i use [node-postgres 'pg'](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) module.

I send this request :

```
query = 'SELECT add_new_views(VARIADIC [$1])';
current_client.query(query, allViews, function(err ,res) {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(res)
})
```

allViews - the array looks like this :

```
[ [ '(b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284)', '(CHUPERM)' ],
  [ '(b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284)', '(HUE)' ],
  [ '(b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284)', '(HU)' ],
  [ '(00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb)', '(HITE)' ],
  [ '(00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb)', '(HIJFIRM)' ],
  [ '(00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb)', '(DVERMNYEZAPILI)' ],
  [ '(00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb)', '(TICHTOMENYANEVIDISH)' ],
  [ '(00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb)', '(HITEBEAD)' ] ]
```

In response, i get :

```
{ [error: malformed record literal: "(b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284)"]
  name: 'error',
  length: 133,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: 'Too few columns.',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'rowtypes.c',
  line: '183',
  routine: 'record_in' }
```

If remove brackets from elements allView array, i got error "Waiting for brackets".
When i try pass to postgres simple one-dimension array, all was ok(ofc i change everything that's needed in postgre function). But with this composite type array i can't do anything. Please help. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I forgot, i try to generate allViews like this : 
[ { event_id: 'b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284',
    device_code: 'CHUPERM' }, .... ]. In response, i got errors.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution for the problem you were having?

Answer (score 1):

The answer may be late, but solves this query. The right syntax that [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) requires is:

```
[
   '(b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284, CHUPERM)',
   '(b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284, HUE)',
    ...
]
```

Instead of two dimensional array, a string representation of the row in a one dimensional array is required.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure you need parentesis between every single statement? I see htat in the example you posted form the pgadmin they do not have parenthesis, probably you should remove them

```
[ [ 'b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284', 'CHUPERM' ],
  [ 'b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284', 'HUE' ],
  [ 'b9d78fc3-b55a-452e-b935-8ce4f1e79284', 'HU' ],
  [ '00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb', 'HITE' ],
  [ '00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb', 'HIJFIRM' ],
  [ '00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb', 'DVERMNYEZAPILI' ],
  [ '00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb', 'TICHTOMENYANEVIDISH' ],
  [ '00ae9a6c-781f-48d1-ab42-bfa87d09bdbb', 'HITEBEAD' ] ]
```

Comment: I mean the `(` and `)` why do you have them in the array? while in the query you do in pgadmin you do not have them

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand it. I wrote about remove brackets(parenthesis) in the end of question. If i remove them, i got an error "Waiting for brackets".